# Best approach to update wrapped object

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, oop, design-patterns

I'm using VB.NET but this question applies to any OO language - Java, C# etc. I've tagged the question with Java and C# but will remove if not considered appropriate.

I have an entity class `ClassAAA` that contains a reference to `ClassBBB` as one of it's attributes:

```
Public Class ClassAAA

    Private Property _blah As ClassBBB = Nothing
    Private Property _somethingElse As String
    Private Property _anotherthing As String

    ' Make it private so cannot instantiate class without supplying ClassBBB '
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByRef value As ClassBBB)
        _blah = value
    End Sub

    Public Property ImportantAttribute As String
        Get
            Return _blah.Imp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _blah.Imp = value
        End Set
     End Property

      ' other stuff '
End Class
```

I don't want to expose `ClassBBB` outside the entity class. This is my question: I want to do an update on `ClassAAA` and I have a static / Shared update method for `ClassBBB` that I want to use. What's the best way to do this?

```
Public Shared Sub UpdateClassAAA(byRef value as ClassAAA)

   ' XXX Cannot do this because ClassBBB reference is private XXX '
    ClassBBBDAO.update(value._blah)

    ' Do other updates on other ClassAAA attributes '

End Sub
```

I could make the `ClassBBB` reference public (or supply a public getter method) but that would expose the inner workings of `ClassAAA`.

What I'm thinking of doing is making the `ClassBBB` reference `Friend` so that it is only visible in the assembly i.e. a data layer and is not visible to client projects. But this stills feel like I'm exposing the inner workings of the class.

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `ClassAAA` hides and encapsulates `ClassBBB` then it is `ClassAAA` that should have a public method to **internally** update `ClassBBB`. The [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) design pattern is an excellent example that illustrates a solution to your problem in a nice and elegant way.

Comment: Yeah, guess you're right - I'm going to have to move away from shared / static CRUD methods and move them into the entity classes themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I think, the simple idea would be to make a public update method *inside* `ClassAAA`, and make other classes call it on demand. This way you don't expose the inner details of `ClassAAA`, but make it possible for others to activate the needed functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only have to make a getter for ClassBBB member or make the update method a class method and not static